# on selecting a row on left jqgrid, the associated rows should be highlighted in right side jqgrid

Tags: java, jqgrid

I have a requirement, where i will be having two jqgrids in a single page. #grid1 is list of roles and #grid2 is list of operations that a particular role can perform. Now when i select a row(role) in grid1, the operations associated to these particular role should be highlighted in some color in grid2. 
I am including my code here

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Role Management</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js'>         </script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<style type='text/css'>

.ui-jqgrid-btable .ui-state-highlight { background: yellow; }
.ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-jqgrid-labels {background-color:green}
..ui-pg-table {background:green}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-widget-header {
border: 1px solid #0b3e6f;
background: #7da600;
color: #40453a;
}
  .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv { overflow-y: scroll }
  </style>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 var lastSel,lastSel1,
 grid=$("#roleMgmtTable"),
 gridavail=$("#AvailableOperations");
 grid.jqGrid({
 url: "rolesList",
 datatype: "json", 
 jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "ref"},
 colNames:['Id','role Name','Description', 'Status'],
 colModel:[
 {name:'roleId',index:'roleId',width:150,editable:true,sorttype:'text',hidden:true},{name:'roleName',index:'roleName',width:150,editable:true,sorttype:'text',editrules:{text:true},},{name:'description',index:'description', width:150,editable:true,sorttype:'text'},{name:'status',index:'status', width:150,editable:true,sorttype:'text'}],
 rowList:[10, 20, 50, 100],
 pager: "#pagingDiv",
 viewrecords: true,
 sortname: 'roleName',
 sortorder: "asc",
 editurl: "LoadJsonDataServlet?type=BS21 7RH",
 caption: "Role Management",
 height:200,
 editurl: 'rolesList',
 ondblClickRow: function(id, ri, ci) {

                grid.jqGrid('editRow',id,true,null,null, 'rolesList');
            },
        });

        grid.jqGrid('navGrid',"#pagingDiv",{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:false, refresh:false},
                // Edit options
                {
                savekey: [true, 13],
                reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                //jqModal: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                height:300,
                width:500,
                bSubmit: "Update",
                bCancel: "Close",
                bClose: "Close",
                editCaption: "Edit Record"

            },
            // Add options
                 {
                     savekey: [true, 13],
                     reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                     //jqModal: true,
                     height:300,
                     width:500,
                     bSubmit: "Save",
                     bCancel: "Close",
                     bClose: "Close",
                     addCaption: "Add Record",
                     closeOnEscape: true,
                     closeAfterAdd: true, 
                     closeOnEscape: true
                },
            // Delete options
                   { 
                        closeOnEscape: true, 
                        multipleSearch: false,
                        reloadAfterSubmit:true,
                        closeAfterSearch: false,
                        bSubmit: "Delete",
                         bCancel: "Close",
                         bClose: "Close",
                         onclickSubmit: function (params) {  
                                var list = $("#roleMgmtTable");
                                var selectedRow = list.getGridParam("selrow");
                                rowData = list.getRowData(selectedRow);
                                return rowData;
                            }
                   }
                   );


        gridavail.jqGrid({
 url: "optsList",
 datatype: "json",
 jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "ref"},
 colNames:['Id','Name','Description'],
colModel:    [{name:'id',index:'id',width:150,editable:true,sorttype:'text',hidden:true},{name:'name',index:'name', width:150,editable:true,sorttype:'text',editrules:{text:true},},{name:'description',index:'description',width:300,editable:true,sorttype:'text'}],
rowList:[10,20,60,100],
pager: "#pagingDiv1",
viewrecords: true,
sortname: 'name',
sortorder: "asc",
editurl: "LoadJsonDataServlet?type=BS21 7RH",
caption: "Available Operations",
height:200,
multiselect: true,
editurl: 'clientArray',
         ondblClickRow: function(id, ri, ci) {
                // edit the row and save it on press "enter" key
                gridavail.jqGrid('editRow',id,true,null,null, 'clientArray');
            },
            onSelectRow: function(id) {
                if (id && id !== lastSel1) {
                    if (typeof lastSel1 !== "undefined") {
                        gridavail.jqGrid('restoreRow',lastSel1);
                    }
                    lastSel1 = id;
                }
     }
     });
$('#save_role_operation').click(function(){
 var myGrid = $("#roleMgmtTable");
 selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
 roleIdValue = myGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', selRowId, 'roleId');
 var avaGrid = $("#AvailableOperations");
 selopIds = avaGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
 selOpArrVal=""
 if(selopIds==""){
  }else if(selopIds!=""){
  selOpArr = selopIds.toString().split(",");
  for(i=0;i<selOpArr.length;i++){
   if(i < selOpArr.length-1){
    selOpArrVal = selOpArrVal + avaGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', selOpArr[i], 'id') +",";
}else if(i==selOpArr.length-1){
selOpArrVal = selOpArrVal + avaGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', selOpArr[i], 'id');
}
}
console.log("roleId value="+roleIdValue);
console.log("selOpArrVal value="+selOpArrVal);

$.ajax({
  data: {"roleId":roleIdValue,"avaOpList":selOpArrVal},
  success: function(data){
    console.log("device control succeeded"+data);
  },
  error: function(errMsg){
    console.log("Device control failed");
 },
 type: 'POST',
 url: "roleOperationsList"
 });

}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id='myForm'>
<div style="float:left;width:1155px;height:100%">
<table border=0>
    <tr>
    <td style="border-left: 3px solid #cdd0d4;"/>       
    <td>
    <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr><td bgcolor="#666666" style="color:white">Application Roles</td>                                      </tr>
    <tr>                        
    <td>
    <div>
    <div style="width:100%;border:1px;">
    <div style="float: left;border:1px;">
    <table id="roleMgmtTable"></table>
    <div id="pagingDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;padding:0px 0px 0px 20px">
    <table id="AvailableOperations"></table>
    <div id="pagingDiv1"></div>
    <div style="float:left;">
    <div style="padding:10px 0px 0p 0px">
    <div style="float: left;background: #7da600;">
    <button class="save_role_operation" id="save_role_operation">Save Role Operation</button></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td style="border-left: 3px solid #cdd0d4;"/>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div >
    <div style="display:inline-block;" ><a href="Home">Home</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

when i select role on left grid and operations on right grid and click on the button save role operations, the roleId and operationId will be saved into an association table with columns role_id and operation_id. SO now if i select the role(row), i should see the associated operations for this in the right grid.[image]
can anyone help me through this?

Comment: You should include more full example. Which information is in the left grid (#grid1 with the list of roles)? **Where you get the information about the associated operations?** (Do you hold the information in a map variable or in hidden column or in the map saved in `userData`, ...) Is the second grid (#grid2 with the list of operations) multi-selectable (do you use `multiselect: true` option in the second grid)?

Comment: for grid1 has the data like rolename,description and status, and i am getting the data from server(database). yes the grid2 is multi-selectable. for both grid data is from server(database) as json type.

Comment: You should click "edit" link under the question and add additional information so that the people who read the text could quickly understand what you do and what problem you have. The information important for **understanding** of your question should not stay in the comments only. it's still unclear the main question which I wrote bold in my previous comment. So you have two grids. The first in single-line select mode and the second have `multiselect: true` option. Both grids have `datatype: "json"`. The second grid contains **all available** operations. The first one contains roles.

Comment: You want to select associated operations in the second grid based on the role selected in the first grid. Thus you have to hold somewhere the information about the operations associated to the role. **Where is the information?** For example the first grid can have *additional hidden column* which contains comma separated ids of operations. You can get the information inside of `onSelectRow` callback in the first grid and you can use, `getCell` to get ids of operations for the selected role and you can use `setSelection` method to select the rows in the second grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `onSelectRow` callback on left grid (master grid). The callback will be called by jqGrid after a row in the left grid (master grid) will be selected. You will get the `id` of the selected row (the `rowid`).

The next step: you should get somewhere the information which operations are associated with the role. For example you can hold the information in the hidden column of roles grid. You need to include the information in the server response which you use for filling the grid. The `operationIds` column of Roles grid can contains for example comma separated list of the ids of operations. In the case the implementation could be the following:

```
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    var operationIds = $(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "operationIds").split(","),
        i, n = operationIds.length;
    gridavail.jqGrid("resetSelection");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        gridavail.jqGrid("setSelection", operationIds[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, I changed my code as the operationIds column of roles grid contains comma seperated list of the ids of operations. but when i select the row, the related operations are not selected. I try keeping alert(operationIds), the ids are displayed correctly. what might be the issue? One more doubt in the code " $gridOper = $("#oper");" what does #oper specify

Comment: @supraja: You should use `gridavail("setSelection", operationIds[i]);`. `#oper` is `#AvailableOperations` in your case.

Comment: I tried "gridavail.setSelection(operationIds[i]);" and the related operations are selected for role, but if i select another role, the operations for present role and previous roles are also selected. how can i resolve this.

Comment: @supraja: You should include `resetSelection` call. See updated code of my answer.